# If $(u_n)$ is positive and converges towards zero, there exists a decreasing sequence such that $u_n \le v_n$ and $\lim_{n\infty} v_n =0$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

My intuition tells me that if we have a positive sequence $(u_n)$ such that $\lim_{n\infty} u_n =0$, therefore there exists a decreasing sequence $(v_n)$ such that $\forall n, u_n \le v_n$ and $\lim_{n\infty} v_n =0$. Is it true? I can see why it is on some particular cases (for example, if we take $\forall n \ge 1, u_n = \frac{|\cos(n)|}{n}$), but I don't know how to prove it...

Comment: If $(u_{n})$ is positive and converges to $0$, it admits a decreasing subsequence $(u_{n_{k}})$. Maybe you can work with this sequence to create $(v_{n})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just let $$v_n = \sup \{u_k : k \geq n\}.$$
Each $v_n$ is a real number, as the sequence of $u_n$ converges (and is thus bounded). It is also clear that $u_n \leq v_n$ for each $n = 1,2,...$. Finally, observe that the $v_n$ form a decreasing sequence, which converges to the "limit supremum" of the original sequence of $u_n$. $$\lim_{n \to \infty} v_n = \limsup_{n \to \infty} u_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} u_n = 0.$$
There are many resources covering the "limit infimum" and "limit supremum" of (bounded) real valued sequences you can consult.

Edit: If you wish the sequence to strictly decrease, then consider $$w_n = v_n + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n.$$
and use the sequence of $w_n$ instead of $v_n$.

Comment: Nitpick: your $(v_n)$ is non-increasing, not necessarily decreasing, as written.

Comment: Okay I'll make an edit

Comment: I mean, there is an easy fix: construct the final $(w_n)_n$ as $w_n=v_n + 1/2^n$...

Comment: Was just about to do exactly that

Answer (score 1):

- Since $\lim_{n\to\infty} u_n = 0$, setting $\varepsilon = u_0/2$, we know that there exists $N_1\geq 0$ such that $u_n \leq  u_0/2$ for all $n\geq  N_1$.
  Set $v_0=v_1=\dots= v_{N_1} = \max_{1\leq i \leq N_1} u_i$.
- Now, there exists $N_2> N_1$ such that $u_n \leq  u_0/4$ for all $n\geq  N_2$. Set $v_{N_1+1}=v_{N_1+2}=\dots= v_{N_2} = u_0/2$.
- Now, there exists $N_3> N_2$ such that $u_n \leq  u_0/8$ for all $n\geq  N_3$. Set $v_{N_2+1}=v_{N_2+2}=\dots= v_{N_3} = u_0/4$.
- Etc.

You can check that, by construction, $v_n \geq u_n$ for all $n$, and $(v_n)_n$ is non-increasing and has limit $0$. *(Getting decreasing instead of non-increasing is a simple modification: construct the final $(w_n)_n$ as $w_n=v_n + 1/2^n$).*